# Why doesn't the gridview persist the checkbox values between pagination?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, checkbox, gridview, webforms

I am trying to store the checboxes values between paginations so if i go from 1 page to another and ocme back the the checkbox checked would persist.

```
Protected Sub gv_InforWO_PageIndexChanging(sender As Object, e As GridViewPageEventArgs)
       Try
            gv_InforWO.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex

            If chkFiltersAvailable.Checked = False Then
                chkSelectAll.Checked = False
                BindGridInfoWO()
                'btnSync_Click(Nothing, Nothing)
            Else

                BindGridInfoWO()
                ' btnSync_Click(Nothing, Nothing)
            End If

            'checkbox persistence code
            Dim d As Integer = gv_InforWO.PageCount
            Dim values() As Boolean = New Boolean((gv_InforWO.PageSize) - 1) {}
            Dim chb As CheckBox
            Dim count As Integer = 0
            Dim i As Integer = 0
            Do While (i < gv_InforWO.Rows.Count)
                chb = CType(gv_InforWO.Rows(i).FindControl("chkSelect"), CheckBox)
                If (Not (chb) Is Nothing) Then
                    values(i) = chb.Checked
                End If

                i = (i + 1)
            Loop

            Session(("page" + CType(gv_InforWO.PageIndex, String))) = values


        Catch ex As Exception
             lblWaitingMsg.Text= ex.Message 
        End Try
    End Sub
```

On pre-render

```
Protected Sub gv_InforWO_PreRender(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Try
            If (Not (Session(("page" + CType(gv_InforWO.PageIndex, String)))) Is Nothing) Then
                Dim chb As CheckBox
                Dim values() As Boolean = CType(Session(("page" + CType(gv_InforWO.PageIndex, String))), Boolean())
                Dim i As Integer = 0
                Do While (i < gv_InforWO.Rows.Count)
                    chb = CType(gv_InforWO.Rows(i).FindControl("chkSelect"), CheckBox)
                    chb.Checked = values(i)
                    i = (i + 1)
                Loop

            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
       
    End Sub
```

but it doesn't persist the value and comes as false even if I tick the boxes.

Answer (score 0):

If your checkbox is databound to something, my guess would be that you need to either update that source data on PageIndexChanging so that it persists, or if you're going to store the values in the session like you have in your code example, update those values OnRowDataBound rather than at prerender of the whole grid.